# Expo Router Giving ErrorBoundary

Tags: routes, expo, expo-router

I'm submitting my Expo App using `Expo-Router` to iOS Test Flight. Upon doing so there seems to be some issue with `ErrorBoundary`. This only occurs in Test Flight. Within the EXPO GO App everything works as expected.

I suspect it is `ErrorBoundary`, due to some trial and error.

When I submit the App to Test Flight with;

```
export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";
```

I get the black screen with "**Something went wrong, Retry**", although, retrying has no effect.

When I remove the exporting of `ErrorBoundary`, I am just greeted with a blank white screen. Thus deducing an ErrorBoundary has occurred somewhere.

1. How do I get the logs of the ErrorBoundary whilst in Test Flight (as everything works in EXPO GO App)?
2. Have I done something wrong in my code?

### _layout.jsx

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ animation: "none" }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ animation: "none" }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="(create-account)"
        options={{ presentation: "fullScreenModal" }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

### index.jsx

Here I check if there is a user or not, based on the result I replace the route.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "../config/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { View, Text } from "../components/UI/Themed";

export default function RootScreen() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        router.replace("(tabs)/home");
      } else {
        router.replace("(auth)/onboard");
      }
    });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Splash Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

### NOTE

I do see "Splash Screen" upon loading, meaning my root index file in the app should be ok. After that it's either the black or white screen mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and this is what helped me figure out the cause of the error with XCode for the ios build:

- prebuild with the production APP_VARIANT (`APP_VARIANT=prod expo prebuild -p ios --clean`
- open the project with XCode (`open ios/myapp.xcworkspace`)
- `Run` the project
- Wait for the `Running myapp on iPhone` message

You should now be able to see the app logs in XCode which should tell you more about the error message. In my case, I had the following error `ReferenceError: Property 'TextEncoder' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes` before `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ErrorBoundary' of undefined`.

Note that the reason why you might not see this error in development is because, if you use expo router, the routes will be loaded lazily in development, but eagerly in production. You can use the `_sitemap` route, to go systematically through all your routes to check if the error comes from any of them.